# Python: Using re and update cursor over three columns

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1

I'm working on this code and got a little to excited...only to find out it wasn't perfect!
I'm trying to eliminate the suffix (row1) of roadnames(row0) and parse just the roadname to a new field(row2). I got it to work, however it also eliminates the suffix within the roadname.
For instance, in the suffix column I could have "St" and roadname "Bathhurst St" What I want is for the new field to say "Bathhurst"  instead, it says "Bathur".

I know if you add a '$' it will make it match to just the end of the field, however I can't figure out how to make it work with variables. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
import re

fc = r"G:\GIS\Shapes\SeptParcels.shp"
fields = ["STREETNAME", "SUFFIX", "NAME1"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row0 = str(row[0])
        print row0
        row1 = str(row[1])
        print row1
        query = re.sub(row1,"", row0)
        row[2] = query
        print query

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Since this is really just a regexp question, I would suggest removing the ArcGIS bits and ask it on StackOverflow. Include clear test cases as they tend to be rather unforgiving of newbies and unclear questions.

Comment: @blah238 Since I'm working with ArcGIS I thought it would be best to ask people who are familiar with UpdateCursors, or people who would be able to suggest alternate solutions to what I've tried above.

Comment: Sorry, but If I understand correctly your question, it is a problem of regex, and not of Arcpy cursors (re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be able to just modify row1 before you do the regexp match.

```
import arcpy
import re

fc = r"G:\GIS\Shapes\SeptParcels.shp"
fields = ["STREETNAME", "SUFFIX", "NAME1"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row0 = str(row[0])
        print row0
        row1 = str(row[1]) + '$'
        print row1
        query = re.sub(row1,"", row0)
        row[2] = query
        print query

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You can clean this up a lot too and cut down on the number of variables involved.

```
import arcpy
import re

fc = r"G:\GIS\Shapes\SeptParcels.shp"
fields = ["STREETNAME", "SUFFIX", "NAME1"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2] = re.sub(row[1]+'$','',row[0]).strip()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Such a simple solution, I feel silly for asking!